# Schur factorisation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to find the Schur factorisation of the matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Where

$$A = \frac{1}{100}\begin{bmatrix}92 && 0 && -144\\0 && 100 && 0\\-144 && 0 && 8\end{bmatrix}$$

I've found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda = -1,1,2$.

I understand the next step is to select one (I'll pick $\lambda = 1$ for convenience) and calculate the normalised vector $\mathbf{A - I}$ where I get to the point

$$\mathbf{A - I} = \frac{1}{100}\begin{bmatrix}-8 && 0 && -144\\ 0 && 0 && 0\\-144 && 0 && -92\end{bmatrix}$$

But I'm unsure on how to normalise this matrix as usually we only have a 1x2 matrix in previous examples.

Comment: what is a schur factorisation?

Comment: from my understanding it's a decomposition of A where $\mathbf{A = UTU^T}$ where **T** is upper triangular and **U** is unitary and **$U^T$** is it's conjugate transpose.

Comment: suppose we have  the normalised ($u^\top u = 1$) eigenvector $u$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1,$ then you can deflate the matrix $A$ by $A - uu^\top$ which has $e_1$ for the first column. now work with the $2 \times  2$  matrix in the corner.